# Fancybox trouble: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

i'm with a little trouble here. Trying to install fancybox i'm getting this javascript error:

```
'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("a.fancybox").fancybox()')
```

here is my HTML

```
<a href="http://localhost/vm/wp-content/gallery/txt/l2.jpg" class="fancybox">
<img src="http://localhost/vm/wp-content/gallery/testando/thumbs/thumbs_l2.jpg">
</a>
```

and my javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.fancybox").fancybox();
});
</script>
```

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Thanks !

Comment: First idea is the overall setup of your scripts. You are "Trying to install fancybox" and obviously you're not successful yet, your HTML + Javascript (which is correct) is the prove :)

Comment: But in other page is working fine with the same script ! But in this one the images are generated using a php foreach function .

Comment: I have removed the `syntax-error` tag, since the error is not a syntax error (actually, it is a reference error). If you need an answer, you should show the generated contents of your whole page, either inline (if the code is not too big), through a link, or in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [jsbin](http://jsbin.com).

Comment: Heve you checked that fancybox js file is correctly referenced?

Comment: Yes, like i said, is working fine in other page with the same scripts !

Comment: Maybe the call of fancybox stands after the include of fancybox sources?

Comment: I am see one error in your code. Image tag is not closed. Apart from this, I am not sure what is the show stopper here. Try scanning this help on Fancybox How to website http://fancybox.net/howto.                      Have you been using any other libraries of javascript ?

Comment: Just moved the script to the bottom of the page and now i'm getting this error: jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js:44 TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'b.support.opacity')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using fancybox v1.3.x because that version cannot display dynamically added elements in Fancybox (FYI Fancybox v2.x can handle existing and dynamically added elements).

If you don't want to upgrade to Fancybox v2.x then you have two options:

1. Use the jQuery livequery plugin
   or
2. Rebuild you script and use `jQuery delegate()` to trigger fancybox with the new elements

Both options are explained [here](http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/83c3cedb0acf0146/).

Please notice that using the `jQuery delegate()` solution won't work with Fancybox galleries, only with single elements.

If you don't want to use the livequery plugin and still want to use Fancybox galleries of dynamically added elements, alternatively you could upgrade to jQuery 1.7+ and use the new API `jQuery on()`

I have a [demo page here](http://picssel.com/playground/jquery/jQueryON_13dec11.html) that shows how to use jQuery on() to display Fancybox galleries with existing and dynamically added elements. Please feel free to look at the source code.

Comment: Just changed to fancybox 2.0 and works fine ! Thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 2):

I've run into a similar problem when a page has two copies of jQuery. So, make sure you only have ONE copy of jQuery on your page.

What happens is that Fancybox is extending itself from the first copy of jQuery; but because of a second copy, the document ready is being called from that copy only. And of course Fancybox is not applied to it.

Comment: Was that too! Another plugin calling jQuery then fancybox was not working. Thanks for the tip!