# Lightbox opening in a new page

Tags: javascript, html, lightbox, lightbox2

I am trying to implement a lightbox in my website (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/). I have this code in my index.php head tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
```

And I have this javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
</script>
```

My main page is included in my index like this

```
<?php include 'pages/home.php'; ?>
```

And in the home.php there is this code.

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="images/logo.png"><h4>Title 2</h4></a>
```

When I click on the Title 2, it just opens a new tab with the correct image. Any idea about what is causing the problem?

Comment: Yep, didn't notice this: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(".fancybox").fancybox()')

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8655948/fancybox-trouble-undefined-is-not-a-function) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11570952/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-evaluating-fancybox-fancybox) ?

Comment: check the doctype, in the fancybox website they use:
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

Comment: @karthikr Okey, I did some progresses. I removed another jquery script and it is now showing the image in the same page but there is no black background.

Comment: very hard to guess what is going on. can you create a fiddle and reproduce the issue ? Or may be you need to set opacity

Comment: Finally fixed, I copied the image and made some adjustments and it worked. For anyone else having this problem, check that you only have 1 jquery link!

Answer (score 0):

check the doctype, in the fancybox website they use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```